# 301 Redirect all pages to root, not index.html, and also redirect all non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess

I've been looking for a precise answer to this question for awhile but couldn't find it.

I've launched a one page website in place of an old website with many pages. Now, I want to redirect everything to www.domain.com. The page uses index.html as the homepage, but I don't want to redirect to that, I just want to redirect to the www.domain.com root.

I tried using:

```
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=302,NC,L]
```

But that just broke my stylesheet and didn't redirect anything. Other solutions I've seen have redirected to the index.html but I want to redirect to the / root domain.

Also, I want to be sure to redirect all non-www pages to www pages too. Can someone please help me out?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely something like this in your `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

If you request a folder (and `http://example.com/` is a request to a folder), it will try `index.php` first, then `index.php3`, etc, etc, and the first one that exists it will shown. You'll have to delete that from your `httpd.conf` if you want every request to end up as `http://example.com`. It'll show a directory view of your www-root folder unless that has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# Any direct request for html/php pages
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /[^\?\ ]+\.(html?|php.) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

That won't affect images, or style sheets, etc. Note that this matches against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable because internally the `%{REQUEST_URI}` gets converted to `/index.html` so you can't match against that.

If you want non-existent requests (which would normally result in a 404) to be redirected as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

To force a "www" use:

```
RewiteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```